# how to pass an function in window.addEventListener using react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a function while closing the tab , a pop shows up with leave and cancel, i want to add a function for specific buttons like , if i click on leave button it should call a one function and if i click on cancel button it should call other function. please help me thanks in  advance

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {  
  ev.preventDefault();
    socket.current.emit(
      "logout_patient",
       history.location.state.data.doctorAlias,
       socket.current.id,
       history.location.state.data.patientId
    );  
  return ev.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?'; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this functionality using one event('**beforeunload**').

You can use the window `unload` event to check the user's click on the leave of popup.

`window.requestAnimationFrame` to check you click on cancel.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

```js
const onCancel = () => {
  console.log("I am the 2nd one.");
};
const onLeave = () => {
  console.log("I am the 3rd one.");

  // This loop is just to make sure that the event is fired
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.log(event.returnValue);
  }
};

const onExit = (e) => {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  e.returnValue = "You sure you want to leave?";
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  console.log("I am the 1st one.");
  window.requestAnimationFrame(onCancel);
};

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onExit, { capture: true });
window.addEventListener("unload", onLeave);
```